# ASP.NET Identity change password

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2, reset-password

I need ability to change password for user by admin. So, admin should not enter a current password of user, he should have ability to set a new password. I look at ChangePasswordAsync method, but this method requires to enter old password. So, this method is not appropriate for this task. Therefore I have made it by the following way:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ChangePassword(ViewModels.Admin.ChangePasswordViewModel model)
    {
        var userManager = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var result = await userManager.RemovePasswordAsync(model.UserId);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            result = await userManager.AddPasswordAsync(model.UserId, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("UserList");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.FirstOrDefault());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.FirstOrDefault());
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

it works, but theoretically we can receive error on AddPasswordAsync method. So, old password will be removed but new is not set. It's not good. Any way to do it in "one transaction"?
PS. I seen ResetPasswordAsync method with reset token, seems, it's more safe (because can't be unstable situation with user) but in any case, it does by 2 actions.

Comment: The crux of this question is doing it in one transaction. Would you be satisfied to do it in two transactions and to keep trying until the second one succeeds? If not, you might have to write your own implementation of changing a password.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`ApplicationUserManager` is the  class generated by the ASP.NET Template.

Which means, you can edit it and add any functionality it doesn't have yet. The UserManager class has a protected property named `Store` which stores a reference to the `UserStore` class (or any subclass of it, depending on how you configured your ASP.NET Identity or if you use custom user store implementations, i.e. if you use different database engine like MySQL).

```
public class AplicationUserManager : UserManager<....> 
{
    public async Task<IdentityResult> ChangePasswordAsync(TKey userId, string newPassword) 
    {
        var store = this.Store as IUserPasswordStore;
        if(store==null) 
        {
            var errors = new string[] 
            { 
                "Current UserStore doesn't implement IUserPasswordStore"
            };

            return Task.FromResult<IdentityResult>(new IdentityResult(errors) { Succeeded = false });
        }

        if(PasswordValidator != null)
        {
            var passwordResult = await PasswordValidator.ValidateAsync(password);
            if(!password.Result.Success)
                return passwordResult;
        }

        var newPasswordHash = this.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(newPassword);

        await store.SetPasswordHashAsync(userId, newPasswordHash);
        return Task.FromResult<IdentityResult>(IdentityResult.Success);
    }
}
```

The `UserManager` is nothing else than a wrapper to the underlying `UserStore`. Check out `IUserPasswordStore` interface documentation at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613273(v=vs.108).aspx) on available Methods.

**Edit:**
The `PasswordHasher` is also a public property of the `UserManager` class, see [interface definition here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.ipasswordhasher(v=vs.108).aspx).

**Edit 2:**
Since some people **naively** believe, you can't do password validation this way, I've updated it. The `PasswordValidator` property is also a property of `UserManager` and its as simple as adding 2 lines of code to add password validation too (which wasn't an requirement of the original question though).

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I'm wondering what we could implement, so that the password is changed in one transaction, even though the admin doesn't know the original password.

Comment: This approach is one transaction. You don't need an old password for it, as the newly implemented doesn't use any function of the old one and directly calls `SetPasswordHashAsync` from `UserStore`'s implementation, if there is any. All you need to know is the `userId` and `newPassword` (which you can randomly generate)

Comment: I used this answer but password didn't update to database table unless I add `await store.UpdateAsync(user, cancellation);` after execution of `SetPasswordHashAsync` method. P.S. I have tweaked a little bit this and _user_ is the object of `class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser`.
Why does this happen?

Answer (score 164):

EDIT: I know the OP requested an answer which performs the task in one transaction but I think the code is useful to people.

All the answers use the PasswordHasher directly which isn't a good idea as you will lose some baked in functionality (validation etc).

An alternative (and I would assume the recommended approach) is to create a password reset token and then use that to change the password. Example:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(id);

var token = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);

var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, "MyN3wP@ssw0rd");
```

Comment: This seems to be the proper way and opens a lot of new possibilities. Thank you!

Comment: I like this answer better

Comment: You can of course also use the `PasswordValidator` property which is defined in UserManager to validate it before setting it. But that wasn't a requirement of the original question

Comment: This seems to be the better way, thanks - wanted to still use the built in security checks and IdentityResult. seems iffy to update the value directly

Comment: Excellent answer. One thing to note: it will throw an exception if you don't have a token provider registered. I had to add `.AddDefaultTokenProviders()` to the `IdentityBuilder` fluent chain in Program.cs (e.g. chained after `builder.Services.AddIdentityCore`)

Comment: You may get  this error `No IUserTokenProvider is registered.` if you use the above logic. You can refer to this S.O answer which takes care of this error and updates the password for the identity: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78104147/1807452

Answer (score 74):

This method worked for me:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> changePassword(UsercredentialsModel usermodel)
{
  ApplicationUser user = await AppUserManager.FindByIdAsync(usermodel.Id);
  if (user == null)
  {
    return NotFound();
  }
  user.PasswordHash = AppUserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(usermodel.Password);
  var result = await AppUserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
  if (!result.Succeeded)
  {
    //throw exception......
  }
  return Ok();
}
```

Comment: While this code may well work, a good answer should also explain how it works and why it is a good solution.

Comment: default change password methods in UserManager class first try validating password and do security checks but i updated password value directly like an ordinary field that has no special constraint on it.

Comment: What is UsercredentialsModel?

Comment: UsercredentialsModel is a simple custom class as user model . in my case its something like this   '  public class UsercredentialsModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string VerificationCode { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }' @Dov Miller

Comment: though I feel like it's not the correct way to change password, but it helped me in different scenario where generating ResetToken and Validating the token wasn't possible.

Comment: If you do it this way, you should also update `SecurityStamp`, example: `user.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();`.

Answer (score 16):

In .net core 3.0

```
var token = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, password);
```

Answer (score 15):

I think that the solution is much easier

1. Generate the passwordToken,
2. Reset the password with the generated Token...

```cs
public async Task<IdentityResult> ResetPasswordAsync(ApplicationUser user, string password)
{
    string token = await userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
    return await userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, password);
}
```

Comment: I believe this be user.Id as the parameter for GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync()

Answer (score 7):

This is just a refinement on the answer provided by @Tseng. (I had to tweak it to get it to work).

```
public class AppUserManager : UserManager<AppUser, int>
{
    .
    // standard methods...
    .

    public async Task<IdentityResult> ChangePasswordAsync(AppUser user, string newPassword)
    {
        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));

        var store = this.Store as IUserPasswordStore<AppUser, int>;
        if (store == null)
        {
            var errors = new string[] { "Current UserStore doesn't implement IUserPasswordStore" };
            return IdentityResult.Failed(errors);
        }

        var newPasswordHash = this.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(newPassword);
        await store.SetPasswordHashAsync(user, newPasswordHash);
        await store.UpdateAsync(user);
        return IdentityResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Note: this applies specifically to a modified setup that uses `int` as the primary keys for users and roles. I believe it would simply be a matter of removing the `<AppUser, int>` type args to get it to work with the default ASP.NET Identity setup.

Answer (score 3):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ChangePassword(ChangePwdViewModel usermodel)
        {           
            var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);            
            var result = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(user, usermodel.oldPassword, usermodel.newPassword);
            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                //throw exception......
            }
            return Ok();
        }

public class ChangePwdViewModel
    {  
        [DataType(DataType.Password), Required(ErrorMessage ="Old Password Required")]
        public string oldPassword { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password), Required(ErrorMessage ="New Password Required")]
        public string newPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Note : here UserId i am retrieving  from Current logged User.

Answer (score 2):

For `ASP.NET Core 3.1` users, this is a modernized iteration of the excellent answers provided by @Tseng and @BCA.

`PasswordValidator` is no longer a property on `UserManager` - instead, the property is an `IList PasswordValidators`. Furthermore, Identity now has a `protected UpdatePasswordHash` method that changes the password for you without needing to directly access the `UserStore`, which eliminates the need to manually hash and save the password anyway.

`UserManager` also has a public property, `bool SupportsUserPassword`, which replaces the need to test if `Store` implements `IUserPasswordStore` (internally, this is exactly what `UserManager` does in the `SupportsUserPassword` getter).

Since `UpdatePasswordHash` is `protected`, you do still need to extend the base `UserManager`. Its signature is:

`protected Task<IdentityResult> UpdatePasswordHash(TUser user, string newPassword, bool validatePassword)`

where `validatePassword` represents whether or not to run password validation. This does **not** default to `true`, unfortunately, so it needs to be supplied. The implementation looks like this:

```
public async Task<IdentityResult> ChangePasswordAsync(ApplicationUser user, string newPassword)
{
    if (!SupportsUserPassword)
    {
        return IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError
        {
            Description = "Current UserStore doesn't implement IUserPasswordStore"
        });
    }
            
    var result = await UpdatePasswordHash(user, newPassword, true);
    if (result.Succeeded)
        await UpdateAsync(user);

    return result;
}
```

As before, the first order of business is to ensure the current `UserStore` supports passwords.

Then, simply call `UpdatePasswordHash` with the `ApplicationUser`, the new password, and `true` to update that user's password with validation. If the update was successful, you still have to save the user so call `UpdateAsync`.

Comment: This sounds good, but, when extended UserManager is used, how to inject that everywhere? I have a .NET Core application that uses UserManager in controllers, so I need to inject it. When running, an error is thrown telling that there is no service to inject the custom user manager.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have user's current password and still want to change the password.  What you could do instead remove user's password first and then add the new password. This way you will be able to change user's password without needing current password of that user.

```
await UserManager.RemovePasswordAsync(user);
await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Comment: the problem with this is that if the new password fails validation, you've already removed the existing password. you could try and validate the password before removing the old password, but there's still a risk that adding the password fails, leaving a user with no password and possibly no way to login

Answer (score -1):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ResetUserPassword(string id, string Password)
{
    //     Find User
    var user = await context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == id).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
    if (user == null)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("UserList");
    }
    await UserManager.RemovePasswordAsync(id);
    //     Add a user password only if one does not already exist
    await UserManager.AddPasswordAsync(id, Password);
    return RedirectToAction("UserDetail", new { id = id });
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you are correct. ResetPassword through token is a preferred approach.
Sometime back, I created a complete wrapper over .NET Identity and code can be found [here](https://github.com/techygarg/CodeNode.Identity/blob/master/CodeNode.Identity/IdentityManager.cs). It might be helpful for you. You can also find nuget [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CodeNode.Identity/). I also explained the library in a blog [here](http://%20www.codingeek.com/dotnet/codenode-identity-an-implementation-of-asp-net-identity). This wrapper is easily consumable as nuget and create all required configs during installation.

Comment: Prefer answers with content in them rather than external links. If those links were ever to die for any reason, this answer would be entirely useless. In addition, you're answering a question that is over two years old with an accepted answer two years later without providing any additional value.