# Changing ASP.NET Identity Password

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a class that creates a user by searching for the email and making sure it doesn't exist and it creates a user:

```
public async Task EnsureSeedDataAsync()
    {
        if (await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("test@theworld.com") == null)
        {
            // Add the user.
            var newUser = new CRAMSUser()
            {
                UserName = "test",
                Email = "test@crams.com"
            };

            await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, "P@ssw0rd!");
        }
    }
```

I am trying create another class to change the password, with the same method but I am confused as to how to create a currentUser object to be passed into the RemovePassword and AddPassword calls.  This is what I have so far :

```
    public async Task ChangePassword()
    {
        if (await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("test@theworld.com") != null)
        {
            _userManager.RemovePasswordAsync(currentUser);

            _userManager.AddPasswordAsync(currentUser, "newPassword");
        }
    }
```

**Can someone please direct me in the right direction as I am new to this and don't know how to transfer the currentUser object, that contains the email that is being searched.**

Answer (score 3):

`FindByEmailAsyc` returns the user object, you need to save it to a variable and pass that to the other userManager calls.  Also, the `RemovePassword` and `AddPassword` methods take the key value of your `User` object as a parameter, not the whole `User` object.

```
public async Task ChangePassword()
{

    var currentUser = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("test@theworld.com") 
    if (currentUser != null)
    {
        _userManager.RemovePasswordAsync(currentUser.Id);

        _userManager.AddPasswordAsync(currentUser.Id, "newPassword");
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing it in two operations is not good, if the second operation fails user is effectively w/o a password

Comment: Yeah, using the `ChangePasswordAsync` method is probably better, but I figured that was beyond the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291366/asp-net-identity-change-password/29291561#29291561). It allows changing the password with just the userId & new password, which is useful to allow Administrators to set a users password and doing it in one single transaction.

It boils down to creating a new method which calls the underlying user store directly.