# ASP.NET Identity change password only admin and delete user without e-mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, owin-security

I am trying to implement asp identity and owin security. I implement login, create new user and while create new user I assign role to that user. New user is registered with user name and password **NOT EMAIL**. Only administrator can add new users because he can only access to administrator page.

So next problem is I want allow administrator to reset password and delete users. 
My logic is that I list all users (it is private app so it want be too much users) in gridview and with two buttons do the thing. So I get users but reset not working.

I found questions like this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29291366/asp-net-identity-change-password)
but I didn't find any solution.

This is my add new user method and it's working.

```
var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
var user = new IdentityUser() { UserName = txtUser.Text };

IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, txtPass.Text);

if (result.Succeeded && ddlRole.SelectedValue=="1")
{ 
    var roleresult = manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "User");            
    var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { }, userIdentity);

    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
}
else if (result.Succeeded && ddlRole.SelectedValue == "2")
{
    var roleresult = manager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Administrator");
    var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

    authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { }, userIdentity);
    Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
}
else
{
   StatusMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I tried reset password with this method

```
protected async void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
    var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
    GridViewRow row = ((Button)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    var user = row.Cells[0].Text;
    var token = await manager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
    var result = await manager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, txtNewPass.Text.Trim());

    if (result.Succeeded)
        Literal1.Text = "Uspješno promijenjena lozinka";
    else
        Literal1.Text = "Nismo uspjeli promijeniti lozinku!";
}
```

but it's not working.

If someone can help me with reset password or delete user I appreciate.

Regards

**UPDATE 1**

I get delete user on "classic way"

```
GridViewRow row = ((Button)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
Label lblUserID = row.FindControl("lblUserID") as Label;//Hidden User ID
String conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[""].ToString();

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
    conn.Open();

    string sQuery = "DELETE FROM AspNetUsers WHERE Id=@employeeID";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sQuery, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeID", lblUserID.Text);

    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Literal1.Text = "Uspješno izbrisan korisnik <span class=\"bg-red\">" + row.Cells[1].Text + "</span>";
        ListUsers();
    }
    catch
    {
        Literal1.Text = "<span class=\"bg-red\">Neuspješno brisanje</span>";
    }
}
```

I don't know is this good choice considering security issues.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the user object to GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync right now you are passing a string inside a var

```
var user =manager.FindByNameAsync(row.Cells[0].Text);//Hoping that row.Cells[0].Text is username of the user
var token = await manager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
var result = await manager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, txtNewPass.Text.Trim());
```

Comment: I got error: argument 1: cannot convert from 'system.threading.tasks.task<microsoft.aspnet.identity.entityframework.identityuser>' to 'string'

Comment: protected async void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
        var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
        GridViewRow row = ((Button)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        var user = manager.FindByNameAsync(row.Cells[0].Text.Trim());
        var token = await manager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
        var result = await manager.ResetPasswordAsync(user, token, txtNewPass.Text.Trim());
        if (result.Succeeded)
           
    }