# How can I change the user's password keeping the Configure IdentityOptions options in the input input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I searched several places for how to change a user's password elegantly.

The one I came closest to using was the one in this post:
[ASP.NET Identity reset password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524111/asp-net-identity-reset-password/)

My algorithm:

```cs
ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Id);  

user.UserName = model.Name;
user.Email = model.Email; 
 
if(model.ChangePassword != null)
{
    var newPasswordHash = _userManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(user, model.ChangePassword);
    user.PasswordHash = newPasswordHash;
}

identityResult = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

But this way the administrator, when filling this field, will not have the validity of `IdentityOptions`.

Comment: This is not C code. Please review and correct your tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should be a comment but I cannot comment, try using `UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync` and `UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync` or inherit from UserManager and you will have access to protected method `UpdatePasswordHash(TUser user, string newPassword, bool validatePassword)` ([source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/b51b838d0e269bb552c6ee04b8824168f1183b0d/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L2400)) which you can expose with your own API.