# AspNet.Identity 'ResetPasswordAsync' and 'ChangePasswordAsync' not working or corrupt

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-identity

I have an app that has been working OK for several years, suddenly this past week some users could not login even though they were using the correct credentials.

I am usisng Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core

DotNet Framework v4.0.30319

I tried to fix this by calling the same APIs from Postman that I have been using successfully since the app was first deployed – to no avail.

I reset the user password using the API with this code for doing the reset:

```
string resetToken = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(token.AspNetUserId);
IdentityResult passwordChangeResult = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(token.AspNetUserId, resetToken, newPassword);
```

But when I check the AspNetUsers table I see that the values for "PasswordHash" and "SecurityStamp" have not changed.

Furthermore, if I do a reset on a user that can still successfully login, after doing the password reset, I can still login using the old password.

In summary, calling:

```
await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync
```

returns success, but does not reset anything.

any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: can you put a trace to see if anything happens in the db at all when you try to reset? and also print out the token values you get back

Comment: Thanks @siggemannen.  1) how do I set the trace in the db, 2) yes I can print the token value, but what do I do with the printed value?

Comment: you could check if it makes sense / is different for different calls. Hmm, for trace, run SQL Server profiler.

Comment: This is the token and I don't know how to determin if it makes sense:  K1qVqY82cpGelZUNo4EiJ7lTbkmdF0eTb80PsowWnn91hLlQulovh+L52XSCE8/Pi5wByIEYPji8JMMQ3t593CxFO778gAI4KgpgzTowvqMnzA/yPs4+AiTqdjwDauRxjcu356yB3sCMfyn+EV4BtmPHLAgsLWXDiWIGK5QDOEH+jX3/98ql6wmDIO/6h5WXokDyiwyrOD3IIcSjX+ChIw==

Comment: @spacedog Not sure what error you are getting here? Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78104147/1807452